# A verb for "assignment"

Tags: word-choice, word-request, collocations

I wrote:

> These are a sequence of assignments to the context variables. They are **(performed/done/executed/applied/...)** when the conditions are met.

Which of the verbs above is appropriate? Sometimes I use "perform" instead of "done" to make the sentence more formal! Am I right?

The common meanings and collocations found in dictionary or google are most around task assignments, school assignments... with verbs like ***give*, *get*, *receive*, *take on, carry out, do, write, complete*** and less about my purpose.

Comment: You might also use ***made, invoked, enacted, effected, carried out*** and doubtless several other verbs. Apart from "stylistic preference" there's really no reason to pick one over another, so I think this question is effectively Off Topic writing advice (Primarily Opinion-Based).

Comment: The verb of assignment is obviously assign.

Comment: @curiousdannii assignments are assigned?

Comment: @fumblefingers I even didn't know they are mater of style. I tought just some of them work.

Comment: You obviously *did* think "style" was relevant, since you've suggested that ***performed*** might be more "formal" than ***done***. Which I don't particularly endorse myself. I think *idiomatically,* assignments are more often ***made*** than ***done*** or ***performed***, but I don't see this as a matter of formal/informal register (except insofar as some people might mistakenly think that longer words are *by definition* more formal than shorter common words).

Comment: @fumblefingers  They were some guess to find the proper verb otherwise I didn't know "made" is also applicable. Thanks

Comment: @fumblefingers the question about "perform" and "done" was just a side question! I wasn't sure either works.

Comment: @Ahmad: My closevote implies no criticism of you for asking the question (I don't endorse the *downvote*). As it happens, if you search for **these assignments are [asterisk]** in Google NGrams, it turns out that **made** is in fact the most common word that might come next. So that information satisfies at least *part* of your question here. But I hope you'll agree with me that ELL shouldn't really be in the business of hosting Answers discussing the stylistic implications of choosing between multiple verbs which are effectively synonymous for the given context.

Comment: @fumblefingers I do agree. However as you know assignment has many meanings. The common meanings found in dictionary or google are most around job assignment, practices... and less about my purpose. Also I still don't know "perform" and "do" for which words are used in general.

Comment: Problem here is how the sentence begins with a number dissonance (a sequence are).  *The context variables **are assigned in sequence** when the conditions are met.*

Comment: @Ahmad: Now you've raised that "job assignment / variable assignment" distinction, it does occur to me that *We **give** these assignments to our best agents* is perfectly natural English, whereas *We give these assignments to integer variables* sounds a bit weird (I'd be more likely to say *We **assign these values** to integer variables*).

Answer (score 1):

**Assignment** here is an activity derived from  a verb (*assign*) rather a noun like "class assignments". Such activities may take "perform" or "do", "make" or similar verbs, but another solution is to use them as a verb with their arguments. Then I rephrased the sentence as:

> **It is** a sequence of assignments to the context variables. The variables **are assigned** when the conditions are met.